# How can I setup a define with requirejs for social plugins (Facebook Like/Share, Tweet, +1)

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, twitter, requirejs

I'm starting to use RequireJS within a project that uses a lot of javascript and trying to add social plugins via requirejs. I already can do this normally in jQuery via the following:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function()
{
(function() {
var po = document.createElement('script');
po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
po.src = '//apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
})
();

window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
_gas.init(FB);
};
(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=xxxxxxxxxxxxx";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

!function(d,s,id){
var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';
if(!d.getElementById(id)) {
js=d.createElement(s);
js.id=id;
js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);
}
}
(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');

});
```

However if I simply wrap it in a define for requirejs the plugins don't load:

```
define(["jquery"], function($) {
$(function(b){
  (function() {
    var po = document.createElement('script');
    po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
    po.src = '//apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
  })
  ();

  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    _gas.init(FB);
  };
  (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

  !function(d,s,id){
    var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';
    if(!d.getElementById(id)) {
    js=d.createElement(s);
    js.id=id;
    js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);
    }
  }
  (document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');

});
});
```

Can you provide an example define of how to accomplish this?

Adding: Main.js:

```
define(["jquery", "jquery.nav", "jquery.social"], function($) {
    $(function(a));
    $(function(b));
});
```

Adding: jquery.nav.js:

```
define(["jquery"], function($) {
$(function(a){
  a("ul.navigation li ul").each(function(){
    a(this).hide()});
    a("ul.navigation li").hover(function(){
      jQuery(this).find("ul:first").slideToggle("fast")
    },
    function(){
      setTimeout(function(){
        jQuery(this).find("ul:first").slideToggle("slow")
      },
      5000)
    })
});
});
```

The navigation works as intended, function a.

Comment: Solved, see my example at CodeReview: [http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/51074/using-requirejs-correctly-for-social-plugins][1]


  [1]: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/51074/using-requirejs-correctly-for-social-plugins